# Debug all functions fired on a specific event

Tags: javascript, debugging, dom-events

I'm trying to see all fired functions on window scroll/resize or any other window events. Is there any way to debug this on Chrome? Maybe with any plugin?

Note: I don't want to detect the target element of event. I want to list all callbacks that are added to fire up with an event.

For example, think I have some callbacks on load like this:

```
window.addEventListener( 'load' , callback_function_a );
window.addEventListener( 'load' , callback_function_b );
window.addEventListener( 'load' , callback_function_c );
window.addEventListener( 'load' , function() {
    // do something
});
```

Now I want to list all those callbacks which are bound with 'load' event on window. Maybe there could be a way to debug the information in array or object like:

```
{
    'callback_function_a',
    'callback_function_b',
    'callback_function_c',
    'anonymous function',
}
```

or something else maybe?

Comment: With the chrome inspector, you can select an element, then click on the 'Event Listeners' tab and see all listeners registered to that element, but I don't know of any way to follow the propagation of an event.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I detect scroll end of the specified element by JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527296/how-can-i-detect-scroll-end-of-the-specified-element-by-javascript)

Comment: or possible duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12522807/scroll-event-listener-javascript

Comment: I'm not going to detect the event target. I want to list all the callbacks that fires with any specified event.

Comment: maybe you can use `monitorEvents` https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/commandline-api#monitoreventsobject-events

Comment: you could also try using breakpoints in dev tools

Comment: You cannot add strings as event listeners. Those calls most likely have been ignored and the strings are not stored anywhere (and cannot be inspected either).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`getEventListeners(object)`](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference#geteventlistenersobject):

```js
// Works in console only
function callback_function_a() {}
function callback_function_b() {}
function callback_function_c() {}

window.addEventListener( 'load' , callback_function_a );
window.addEventListener( 'load' , callback_function_b );
window.addEventListener( 'load' , callback_function_c );
window.addEventListener( 'load' , function() {});

const listenerNames = getEventListeners(window).load.map(getListenerName);

console.log(listenerNames);

function getListenerName(entry) {
  return entry.listener.name ? entry.listener.name : 'anonymous'
}
```

Here is an example:

[image: Print all <code>load</code> event listeners]