# How to detect the end of an element scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to make an automatic scroll bar scrolling to left then when the scrollbar reaches the end it comes back ... now the issue is that im not able to detect the end of the scrolling since `element.scrollWidth` returns a static  value of the whole element length including the overflowed part i guess ... and `element.scrollLeft` returns a non-static value that changes dependently on the screen width since the element is responsive .

here is a snippet of what i've tried so far :

```js
const slider = document.getElementById('container');
var i = 1;
setInterval(() => {
  i === slider.scrollWidth ? (i = -i , i++) : i++
  slider.scrollBy(i  / Math.abs(i), 0);
}, 5)
```

```css
#container {
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}

#start,
#end {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: white
}

#start {
  left: 1%;
}

#end {
  right: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="slider">
    <div id="start"></div>
    <span id="end"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

NB : i want the scrollbar to turn back exactly when it reaches the end

Comment: I'm afraid the snippet works as you wanted. Here, I see the scroll go all the way to the right, waits 2 secs and go back to the beggining. and all over again. Isn't that?

Comment: @MauricioSipmann the delay at the end was because the scroll didnt reach the `scrollWidth` yet i dont want that to happen i want it to come back exactly when it hits the right limit

Answer (score 1):

Aha! I literally had the same issue just recently, took me forever to get the concise answer I wanted!

Here is vaguely my code and an explanation of how it works.

**Firstly, in my default page it calls a script from an external file**. 
This won't be relevant for everyone, but if you want to keep all your auto-scroll crud in a different file to make it look neater, this is how you do it (and call it).

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.getScript('/scripts/scrollableLogic.js', function () {
            var $scrollSpeed = 400000; 
            var $interval = 400000;
            initialiseAutoScroll($scrollSpeed, $interval);
        });
});
```

**Secondly, in my external file, I start all my autoscrolling.** 
Note: I have about 4 divs scrolling independantly, they all have hover selectors that stop scrolling and resume independently of one another. My code might give some insight into how to do this if that's another issue you're facing - if not, just ask and I'll provide more code. Similarly, I know there are variables that remain unused in this code example - this is because my code is far larger / more complex than what's featured here!

```
function initialiseAutoScroll(speed, interval) { 
    //Auto scroll my exampleDiv
     $('#exampleDivName')
        .animate({
        scrollTop: $('#exampleDivName').get(0).scrollHeight 
        }, { duration: speed});

    //Detect when scrolling the div
    $('#exampleDivName').bind('scroll', checkScrollPosition);  
};
```

**Thirdly, fire the event everytime the div is scrolled, when it's at the bottom, do a thing**.

```
function checkScrollPosition(div) {
  var $div = $(div.currentTarget);

  //Allows for margin of error in borders + scroll
  if (($($div).get(0).scrollHeight - $($div).scrollTop() == $($div).innerHeight()) ||
      $($div).get(0).scrollHeight - $($div).scrollTop() <= ($($div).innerHeight() + 
      10)) {
      //Perform logic to restart your scrolling or do whatever you want
    }
  }
}
```

If any of this doesn't appear to make sense, please ask!

**As an update for the comment left:**
All I'm doing is having an event listener for every time the div is scrolled. In side that listener, a function is called. This function looks at the current scroll position of the div as well as it's height, if it's at the bottom, it does a thing.

See definitions: 
**scrollHeight** property returns the entire height of an element in pixels, including padding, but not the border, scrollbar or margin. 
**Element.scrollTop** property gets or sets the number of pixels that an element's content is scrolled vertically. 
**innerheight** - current computed inner height (including padding but not border) for the first element in the set of matched elements or set the inner height of every matched element

If you have a quick research at trying to find the Javascript equivalent of these functions, and just pop them into your equivalent function, it should be a good place to start.

If you still have issues after further research, I'll attempt to mock up a Javascript sample for you!

Comment: Thanks for the answer ...i'm having hard time parsing this to vanilla javascript since i don't use JQeury

Comment: Hey, see my updates, hopefully it gives you somewhere to start/decode what is happening in my code!

Comment: Actually, check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5527296/how-can-i-detect-scroll-end-of-the-specified-element-by-javascript