# How to make a slider with start autoplay on hover in both direction

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-animate

I want to start autoplay in slider with an infinite loop. whenever we hover over the navigation element in both direction

Comment: What have you tried so far? Here on SO, we try to help people with their specific problems.

Comment: In this answer, I've described an infinitely scrolling function, but it hints at repeating functions infinitely in Jquery: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57915381/11700321

Comment: @Geshode I managed  to move images in both directions and unable to move in a loop here is pen of my code https://codepen.io/Dushyant9211/pen/bGbmzJa